# Mail.app on Lion with Exchange doesn't get updates

Tags: macos, mail.app, exchange-activesync

I've noticed since upgrading to Lion that Mail.app doesn't seem to update the mailbox and synchronize properly with Exchange.

Before on SL, or using Outlook now, they always maintained correct state, matching with my iPhone, or webmail. Now, it seems that Lion gets lost. I have to force a sync, open and shut it, or change folders to get it to resync that folder contents.

Is this just me, or is this a known issue?

Is there a work around?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the activity and connection doctor windows to make sure it's not a temporary issue?

Comment: I can open up Activity then run a Get New Mail, and it will prompt a flurry of checking, but no change to the inbox. Restart will make it do a proper sync and it's fine. The mailbox isn't indicated as offline.

Comment: Yowsers - might be a bug, then. Connection doctor should show temporary server errors, but it seems you are having to hand tend this more than is warranted.

Comment: I noticed this for the first time today. I'm not sure if it is environment related or Mail.app. I have been in this location many times before without difficulty, so not sure. Did you ever find a solution/workaround?

Comment: I have same issue. Check activity monitor and see if your Mail memory is creeping up over time. Mine would go to 3+GB. Lots of posts online with same issue but no solution so I went to Outlook. :/

Comment: @Minamhere - yes, I switched everything from my hosted exchange setup to iCloud. Now it's just the iPhone that doesn't always sync mail. The Mac is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the rebuild utility through the app, I had a very similar problem and this resolved it for me. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

1) Run the following in Terminal.app:

`sqlite3 ~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope\ Index vacuum`

2) And then select your Inbox, and select Mailbox->rebuild.

Worked for me :)

Comment: What exactly does this command (vacuum) do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a partial work around for this:

Delete (or copy to somewhere else) this file:  `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist`

That stores your preferences for Mail.app, after deleting it you will loose your preferences with the exception of your mail accounts.

This worked for me but a couple of months later the bug came back and I had to delete the file again.