# Mail shows stale inbox count

Tags: macos, mail.app

I've had some odd behavior on my OS X mail client. Heres' my inbox:

[image]

Yet here is how many unread messages I have:

[image]

These values used to be synchronized. Note that the first value will not change even if I mark all other messages as read (subfolders included).

OS X 10.7.4
Mail = Version 5.2 (1278)

Comment: What type of mail account is this? IMAP, POP, Exchange?

Comment: Oh yes, it's Exchange - thanks for the clarification q.

Comment: Is the value of unread mail proper in OWA?

Comment: This looks similar to an issue I had a while back: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21122/mail-app-on-lion-with-exchange-doesnt-get-updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two solutions:

1. From the Finder, ⌥-click the Go menu and select Library whilst still holding ⌥.
2. Move the folder `~/Library/Mail/` to the desktop or another convenient location.
3. Launch Mail.app.
4. From the File Menu choose Import Mailboxes…
5. Choose Import Data from Apple Mail.
6. Navigate to ~/Desktop or wherever you moved `~/Library/Mail/` to.
7. Click on Choose.
8. Wait until it imports.

*or*

1. In a Finder window, navigate to `~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData`, and delete any file that begins with Envelope Index, such as "Envelope Index" or "Envelope Index-shm" or "Envelope Index – awl". In my case, I had all 3 of these Envelope indexes, and moved them to the trash.

   *Note:* When accessing Library, keep in mind that your home Library is hidden in Lion.  To access it, from the Finder, ⌥-click the Go menu and select Library whilst still holding ⌥.
2. Restart Mail. It will then rebuild a new list of messages, which can take some time, so be patient.

   *Another note for Exchange users:* After removing the Envelope Indexes, my Exchange account email content was blank. To revive it, I had to delete my Exchange email account and add it again fresh.  After adding it from scratch (and the download took a while since I have about 12K messages), the mystery Unread Message notifications were gone.

Comment: Damn. Pulled the trigger on the second option without reading all of your response. I have 60k messages coming my way... Update to come.